# Contain Filter and Value does not fall within the expected range. CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom

I had a problem with using Contain filter in CAML query in csom, this is my code :

```
var siteUrl = "/rp/lab/ssite";
var listname = "listview";
var clientContextSO = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oListSO = clientContextSO.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listname);
var camlQuerySO = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuerySO.set_viewXml('<View><Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="ID"/><FieldRef Name="Title" /></ViewFields>\
                    <Where>\
                        <Contain>\
                            <FieldRef Name="column1"/>  \
                            <Value Type="Text">aa</Value>\
                        </Contain>\
                    </Where>\
                        </Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>');
var collListItemSO = oListSO.getItems(camlQuerySO);
clientContextSO.load(collListItemSO);
clientContextSO.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
    var listItemEnumeratorSO = collListItemSO.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumeratorSO.moveNext()) {
        var olistItemEnumeratorSO = listItemEnumeratorSO.get_current();
        console.log(olistItemEnumeratorSO.get_item('Title'));
    }
}), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}));
```

This code works fine with `Eq` filter but When i use Contain this error happened :

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be Contains rather than Contain

Comment: @NadeemYousuf Exactly ! worked ! because of stupid error with out any explanation I can not find out what this is about ! thanks.

Comment: Added it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Contains instead of Contain in the CAML query.